# Compile Qt application on Raspberry Pi and Run that application on other ARM device. Will it work?

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, arm, qt, toolchain

I am compiling One Qt application on Raspberry Pi and Run it on different ARM device like Microchip or TI board without compile again. will it work??? if both the side Qt version is same.

Answer (score 0):

Not only Qt version must be compatible, but also all deps must be in place, the type of build must be binary compatible with the rest of the system etc... for example, if you build for hard float, all systems must be built the same way. Arm arch must be compatible as well. So there are a few conditions to respect.

Docker images, for instance, tend to run on all systems with the same arch. Same for AppImages. But those include the app binary and all the deps properly setup.